# What are the most effective use of L1-3 spell slots for healing multiple party members for a Cleric/Druid multi-class build?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, multi-classing, healing

What are the **most effective use of L1-L3 spell slots** for healing multiple party members for a **Cleric/Druid multi-class** build?

I'm looking for some guidance on the most "cost" effective use of my L1 to L3 spell slots for a multiclass Cleric **(Life Domain)** / Druid **(Circle of the Shepherd)**. I want to work out how to get the most overall healing, while trying to maximise the synergy of my domain/circle features.

The party consists of **6 players** normally.

The maximum spell-slots available for L1-L3 spells are:

- 4 x 1st-level spells
- 3 x 2nd-level spells
- 3 x 3rd-level spells

Level 5 Cleric (Life Domain) (PHB p.60)

- **Disciple of Life**: +2 + spell level (target of the spell)

Level 5 Druid (Circle of the Shepherd) (XGE p.24)

- **Spirit Totem, Unicorn Spirit**: + druid level (all players)

I'm trying to think of how to best use my spell slots in combination with my Spirit Totem (Unicorn) and my Disciple of Life feature.

I think I've worked out a good single or combination for L1 slots...

For Level 1 slots I thought the best one is ***Cure Wounds***:

- one character gets: 1d8 + spellcasting mod (+5 max); +3; +5
- all party members get: +5 (x6)
- Average: (4.5+5+3+5) + (5x6) = 47.5

Second best, use bonus action to cast ***Healing Word***:

- one character gets: 1d4 + spellcasting mod (+5 max); +3; +5
- all party members get: +5 (x6)
- Average: (2.5+5+3+5) + (5x6) = 45.5

I'm not sure for L2 slots, and L3 slots I think ***Mass Healing Word*** would be the obvious choice?

Comment: "Average of both cast in the same round" You can't cast two spell slot spells in the same turn.

Comment: @Eternallord66 Thank you for pointing this out. I've amended this now. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're most concerned with cost-effective and are not concerned with the most time-effective option, the one and only answer is *[Healing Spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-spirit)* (XGtE, p.157).

If you can get your party to dance to your tune (i.e., walk through the effect in an orderly fashion), you can heal all of them for 10d6 each in a minute's time with a 2nd Level slot, or 20d6 with a 3rd Level slot. [If your DM allows Readying movement to pass through it on another character's turn, you can double that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162950/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-maneuver-into-and-out-of-the-healing-spirit-spell-to).

Due to particular wording of each effect (casting a spell vs. using a spell vs. somebody else triggering the effect) and your particular DM's interpretation, *Disciple of Life* and *Spirit Totem* may or may not work in conjunction with it. Really, it doesn't matter, because *Healing Spirit* is far and away the best out-of-combat healing spell in the game - and only Druids and Rangers can have it.

As for 1st Level spells, that is highly dependent on DM interpretation of what *Disciple of Life* and *Spirit Totem* apply to. As one who rules they do not apply to *Goodberry* (because the spell creates objects that can be later used for healing, rather than actually doing any healing upon casting), you've already found your best options - *Cure Wounds* if you can get close, *Healing Word* if you can't. If your DM interprets differently, *Goodberry* may be a better choice.

Comment: You can use readied movement for even more healing, btw

Comment: Doesn't the spell heal you *each turn you enter it*? So if you ready movement to go off on somebody else's turn, you'll heal again?

Comment: You can certainly Ready movement and move on the same turn. The rules just say: "Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it." (you are basically Readying the Dash action)

Comment: You should add what the average heal is with and without readied movement (70-140)

Comment: Since *healing spirit* is a 2nd level spell, you may want to also include whatever you feel in the strongest 1st level healing spell (*healing word*, *cure wounds*, or *goodberry*) or maybe just *goodberry* since the original question doesn't cover it

Comment: @DavidCoffron There is no point to readying Dash. It's a common misconception (particularly from players with experience in earlier D&D systems) that using Dash actually causes/includes movement - it doesn't. What Dash actually does is increase your *available* movement; the movement is separate from the Dash action, because movement is not an action. If you ready a Dash, you increase your available movement on somebody else's turn... where you can't move to begin with. With Ready, you can choose an action *or* movement. However, I'll grant that you can effectively move twice via Ready.

Comment: @T.J.L. I know. That's why I said it is "basically" readying dash (it has the effect one might desire). To get the effect of gaining more movement on someone else's turn you ready movement which equates to the same amount if movement in the round as if you had Dashed on your turn.